# Почему применяя свойство padding иногда не работает margin-top?

Tags: css

```
.load{
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: medium;
        padding: 20px 50px;
        color:#555555;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        border: 1px solid #F4F4F4;
        margin-left: 604px;
        text-decoration: none;
        box-shadow: 0 0 15px#565656;
    }
```

Comment: добавь пример разметки

Comment: прикрепи, пожалуйста html код, так проще тебе помочь)
да, комментарии оставлять пока не могу

Comment: @demid.gromiko, комментарии можно оставлять при наличии 50 баллов репутации, у тебя уже 67, так что вполне можешь сразу комментарии писать.